# Convert apache user to physical account with home directory

Tags: php, linux, apache-http-server, shell

I'm working on Red Hat Linux server, I want to execute shell script from my php application, the script contain ssh connection with a lot of others actions, I want to convert the existing apache account to a user with home directory then I can connect as apache and run `ssh-keygen`

I run those commands

```
grep apache /etc/passwd
usermod --shell /bin/bash apache
grep apache /etc/passwd
```

then I connect as apache `su - apache` , when I run the command `ssh-keygen` I get the error `Could not create directory '/usr/share/httpd/.ssh': Permission denied`
how can I create home directory to apache user `/home/apache/` ?
and how can I authorize apache to run ssh-keygen ?

Comment: `man usermod` have a look at the -m and -d flags. however, I wouldn’t change the user. Better log in, su to root and then su to apache with -s /bin/bash

Comment: I login in to root account then su - apache